# Undo/Redo functionality in VSTO Excel add-in

Tags: excel, vsto, office-interop, excel-addins

I am developing an Excel add-in using VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office) in c#.

I have a custom ribbon which contains custom buttons.
Some of the buttons trigger callback that change the content and style of cells.
I identified that undo/redo actions are not possible after utilizing the add-in's capability.
After thorough search in forums and Q&As here, I discovered that the undo stack is cleared with each interop call.

After thorough search in forums and Q&As here, I discovered that the undo stack is cleared with each interop call.
I noted similar concerns reported by other add-in developers on the Office-js GitHub repository, with acknowledgement from the support team in September 2022. However, no resolution or updates have been provided since.

I wanted to check whether someone has found or can help with a workaround to overcome this "issue"?

Thanks in advance!